# Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for mapper function hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

My input looks like:

```
0RViGi2Rne8,OmnipotentSI,1135,Entertainment,9,490,2.31,26,15
HT_QlOJbDpg,dumbasstheredneck,1095,Comedy,14,1349,2.09,22,13
ShhClb6J-NA,thecrashguy,1136,Entertainment,61,29,0,0,0
g9e1alirMhc,iamdanielisaac,541,Comedy,152,483053,4.65,2689,2932
YZev1imoxX8,threefirstnames,1135,Entertainment,253,63,5,3,2
```

I want my Mapper output to be. I basically want the 4th column to be my Key and I want just the integer 1 as value per key:

```
Entertainment: 1
Comedy: 1
Entertainment: 1
Comedy: 1
Entertainment: 1
```

My mapper class is as shown below. For this, I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3. I am unable to understand why, because on testing on normal java program, my split function returned correct output.

```
public class VidCountByCategory {
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>{
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context)
                throws IOException,InterruptedException {

            String line = value.toString();
            String category = line.split(",")[3];

                value.set(category);
                context.write(value, new IntWritable(1));
        }

    }
```

Can any one please point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Check if all your records have at least 4 fields.

Comment: @ManjunathBallur is right. You can never assume that all of your data will be as you expect. In fact you should automatically assume it's nothing like you expect, and do all the relevant checks to convince yourself that you are dealing with the correct data. Also don't write `new IntWritable(1))` for each record - it's very inefficient. Initialise it once up top.